# Nonstandard models without compactness

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am interested in how the nonstandard models "look like". I get the idea that the usual axioms describing successor and ordering don't preclude the existence of other chains other than the standard natural one, however only because I was told so — I fail to grasp exactly why this is the case.

For instance consider the following sentences,

(S1) $\forall x \exists y (Sx=y)$

(S2) $\forall x,y,z (Sx=y\to Sx=z \to y=z)$

(O1) $\forall x,y(Sx=y\to x<y)$

(O2) $\forall x,y,z(x<y\to y<z \to x<z)$

And most importantly,

(O3) $\forall x,y(x<y\vee y<x \vee x=y)$

I don't see how (O3) does not preclude the existence of points outside the main chain, since it asserts that all elements of the universe are pairwise comparable / the structure is connected — not? I know of the usual compactness argument applicable here though I would be interested in a more constructive way of introducing a nonstandard model for this set of sentences here so I could visualise it.

Comment: You can take ultrapowers of standard models (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct). These are not very explicit but in some sense it is not possible to be much more explicit than this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum's_theorem

Comment: There is a quite detailed exposition into : Martin Goldstern and Haim Judah, [The Incompleteness Phenomenon](https://books.google.it/books?id=1H1FjJG7XzUC) (1995), **Ch.2.3 Nonstandard Models of Arithmetic**, page 120-on.

Comment: Regarding trichotomy (O3), we have that : if $a$ is standard, i.e. $a=S^n(0)$, for some $n$ and $b$ is non-standard, then $a < b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, there is a very simple *non-standard* model. Let $X = \{0,1\} \times \mathbb N$ and let $<$ be the strict lexicographical order on $X$. Let
$$
S \colon X \to X, (a,b) \mapsto (a,b+1).
$$

It's easy to verify that $(X; S, <)$ is a model of (S1),(S2),(O1),(O2),(O3).

Intuitively $(X, <)$ is just $\mathbb N$ with an additional copy of $\mathbb N$ 'put on top'. So the 'non-standard' numbers in this case are of the form $(1,n)$ for $n \in \mathbb N$. And we have that every 'standard' numbers $(0,m)$ is below every non-standard number - a fact that holds true in general, but can be seen very explicitly in this model.

Comment: Oh, of course! How did I miss that. I was too focused on the sentences themselves

Comment: @wet Yeah... when learning new concepts, it's quite easy to focus on details and miss the bigger picture. I'm glad that I could clear things up a little for you. Note also that you can generalize this approach to get ill-founded models: Look at $Y = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb N$ with the strict lexicographical order and the associated successor function.

Comment: Mmm. By ill-founded you mean nonstandard, yes? If you don't mind one more question: I thought of extending your example (which I found pretty cool, BTW) for a language with addition, and then multiplication as well; let $X=\mathbb{N}^{2}$, $(x_{1},y_{1})+(x_{2},y_{2})=(x_{1}+x_{2},y_{1}+y_{2})$ and similarly for multiplication. I think this would be a nonstandard model for Robinson's $Q$ then — or do you see any flaws? If so then I wonder what it is about the induction schema that its introduction makes the nonstandard models available necessarily nonrecursive.

Comment: @wet By ill-founded I mean that there is an infinite $<$-decreasing sequence. Regarding your 2nd question: No, that doesn't work. One reason is the requirement $\forall x ( x = 0 \vee \exists y \colon x = S y )$. In your case this isn't satisfied for $(m,0)$ iff $m > 0$.

Comment: Ah, yes. But then we can just take $X = {0} \times \mathbb{N} \cup \mathbb{N}^{+} \times \mathbb{Z}$ instead, right?

Comment: I mean $X = (\{0\} \times \mathbb{N}) \cup (\mathbb{N}^{+} \times \mathbb{Z})$, for clarity.

Comment: @wet You need to define $\cdot$ before we can check if it works. You should try to make it work and ask a new question if you get stuck along the way.